# adding graphics after labels in d3js tree

Tags: javascript, svg, tree, d3.js

See the d3js tree here http://bl.ocks.org/1061834

I have added labels to the nodes using .append("text").  This works fine.  The labels are strings of different length.

Suppose I want to add graphics, say a circle, after the label, do I need to calculate the length of the string and then add the graphic element?  Do I group the label and the graphic together so I can pass the string length?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to calculate the position of the graphics element you want to add explicitly. The easiest way to do this would probably be to, as you said, put label and graphic together in a group and then use `.getBBox()` on the text to determine the offset for the graphic.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how to group these together?  I know that's what I want to/should do - not sure how

Comment: Sure. You add an SVG `g` element and then underneath that the text and graphic elements. So something along the lines of `var foo = something.add("svg:g").attr("transform", ...); foo.add("svg:text")...; foo.add("svg:circle")...`.

Comment: I don't think I have all I need.  I am not sure how to add an element after another element.  I have a text element.  I want to add, say a circle after that.  I am able to create text, then later select them and check the bbox.  not sure how to add graphics after the text/node

Comment: First you create the group element. Save that as a Javascript variable like I did. Then you `.add()` the other elements to that variable.